# As a working-traveler, is there a way to get around port 80 blockage without touching the router?

Tags: ports

I work while traveling at the moment. I'm at the point where I want to start setting up the paypal integration, but I can't because I can't open port 80 up so that paypal sandbox can communicate with my computer. I've tried getting my own USB modem w/ sim card (data plan) but it seems they are really aggressive with blocking ports on those also.

So, i can't get to the routers in the hotels since it would be wrong (and i don't have the passwords).

Is there some kind of trick that I can use so I can mess with paypal sandbox integration? I've tried using hosting (godaddy) but it's awful slow to keep uploading changes to a host just to see if what you did worked (not to mention problems with debugging).

Comment: How are you getting to web pages at all if port 80 is blocked?

Comment: incoming requests are blocked.

Comment: I see.  In other words, your laptop can't act as an HTTP server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like i didn't get any help this time, but i found a way around it! I created a VPN in Windows 7 in my home network (so my work laptop can connect back home). I checked the setting that allows remote vpn connections to pick their own IP address so my work laptop would have a static ip.

I then simply opened up port 80, and forwarded it to the static IP set for my laptop.  I can't believe it, but it works!